# Right swipe in android closes window

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an android issue that appears to take any right swipe on my base window and either closes it or does an android back command.  Basically closes the app back to home screen.

Also, I am not listening for swipes anywhere.

Ti SDK 5.1.2

Comment: do you use any module in your code? Specifically, `xp.ui`?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Hello, It looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the Appcelerator JIRA https://jira.appcelerator.org/. If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: @RenePot  - yes, I use xp.ui...

Comment: @RenePot thanks, that was it, xp.ui was the culprit.  ---  

Unless you set the NavigationWindow's swipeBack attribute to false or pass this as an option to openWindow, the module will add a swipe-eventlistener to close the window when the user swipes to the right, just like it does on iOS7. For Android, it adds slide_in_left and slide_out_right enter/exit animations unless you pass animated: false as an option for openWindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned your use of `xp.ui` module. This module adds this functionality by default and it can be disabled by providing the `swipeBack = false` option to the module.

Comment: @Keith-Tucci could you accept this answer of Rene since it's the correct one as you mentioned in a comment on your question? Then others can see it is answered as well.